# Allowing public access to two ASP.NET WebForm pages when the rest require authorization

Tags: web-config, webforms

We are adding a couple pages to our application that don't need to be locked down behind a login. How would I open up two pages to be publicly accessible.

Here is my Web.config:

```xml
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ORGANIZATION" loginUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

We want page1.aspx and page2.aspx to be public. How would I allow that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would add a `location` in the web.config to exempt them:

```xml
<configuration>
    <!-- The rest of your web.config -->
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".ORGANIZATION" loginUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="page1.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="page2.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: but is this effective if we have 100 public page??how can i tell only deny page1 and page2 to be a public??

Comment: @JesonPark This won't scale for 100 pages. You should probably use a subdirectory like `public/page1.aspx` and make a web.config in public which allows all files. Alternatively, make your own access engine in ASP.NET and don't use the out-of-box one.

Answer (score 1):

In an authenticated website, you can use the `Location` element in `web.config` to specify that a page can be accessed anonymously.

In this `web.config` section anyone can get to the RecoverPassword page without being authenticated, but no one can access pages in the Admin folder without being authenticated.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="RecoverPassword.aspx">   // specify file    \   only specify one --
  <location path="Admin" >                 // specify folder  /   either file or folder
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="UserLogin.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```